# Why the dynamic linker couldn't resolve reference when a shared library has a dependency on other share library?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, dynamic-linking, linker

Code:

```c
//a.c   I don't use header files as this is just for demo purpose.
extern void function_b(int num);
void function_a(int num) {
   function_b(num)
}
```

```c
//b.c
void function_b(int num) {
   ...
}
```

```c
//dll.c 
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main() {
   void *handle_a;
   void *handle_b;
   void (*pfunc_a)(int);
   ...
   handle_a = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   ...
   pfunc_a = dlsym(handle_a, "function_a");
   ...
   handle_b = dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_GLOBAL);
   ...
   pfunc_a(2020);
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

We can see that `dll.c` tries to load shared library in run time and module `a` has a reference on `function_b` and module `b` has the definition of `function_b`. Let's say we have already created shared libraries `a.so`, and `b.so` so those shared libraries exist on disk before the program runs, but when I run the program, it throws an symbol lookup error:

```
./a.so:undefined symbol: function_b
```

but for this line of code `handle_a = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_LAZY);`
since I use `RTLD_LAZY` here, the runtime linker doesn't try to resolve the symbol `function_b`, and there's an opportunity for me to call `dlopen("b.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)` before calling `function_a`. This way the dynamic linker will modify the reference in `a.so` with the definition of `function_b` in b.so.

My questions are:

- Is my understanding correct that the dynamic linker is supposed to modify the `.got` or `.got.plt` section of `a.so` so that it can be linked/relocated to the instruction address of function_b in the `.text` section of `b.so`.
- If my understanding is correct, then why couldn't the dynamic linker  still resolve `function_b` in this case?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63717392/340790 by an account that is a prolific multi-poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn’t that the dynamic linker can’t resolve `function_b`, it’s that your second call to `dlopen` is incorrect: [you *need* to include either `RTLD_LAZY` or `RTLD_NOW`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), the other flags are complementary to those two.

> One of the following two values must be included in *flags*:

Changing your `b.so` load to

```
handle_b = dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

produces a working program.

Every call to `dlopen` must choose between `RTLD_LAZY` and `RTLD_NOW`; since `b.so` is the last library loaded, I specified `NOW` above (we don’t gain anything by lazy-loading), but `LAZY` works just as well in this instance. On top of that, other flags can be added; here we need `RTLD_GLOBAL` because we need `b.so`’s symbols to be made available globally, so that `function_a` can find `function_b` when it runs.

See [the examples in `dlopen(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html#EXAMPLES) for details of the error-handling you need to do with `dlopen` etc., which reveals the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. could you explain a little bit more , why `RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL` is needed?

Comment: @StephenKitt  so the definition of  `RTLD_NOW`: all undefined symbols in the shared object are resolved before dlopen() returns.  But my `b.so` doesn't  have any undefined symbols, why it still need to be loaded  it with  `RTLD_NOW`?

Comment: Because `dlopen` requires you to specify `LAZY` or `NOW`. If you don’t, it fails with an “invalid flags” error. Try adding error-handling to your example and you’ll see.